# Proving adding finitely many points to a set does not change its derived set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is a question in Michael Schramm's Introduction to Real Analysis where he asks to prove that adding finitely many points to a set does not change its derived set. That is, we need to show that, if $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $A \subset X$ and $x\not \in A$ then $(A \cup \{x\})' = A'$.

---

Here is my attempt at proving this result:

Let $x\in X\setminus A$. There are two cases: $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ or $x$ is not an accumulation point of A. First, we handle the first case.

Suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ be given. Let $y \in (A \cup \{ x \})'$. If $y=x$ then there is nothing to prove because $y$ would be in $A'$ by our assumption. Hence, we assume that $y\ne x$. Let $\varepsilon_1 := \min \{ \varepsilon , d(x,y) \}$. Thus, $B(y,\varepsilon _1) \cap ((A \cup\{x\})\setminus\{y\})\ne \emptyset$. Let $z\in B(y,\varepsilon _1) \cap ((A \cup\{x\})\setminus\{y\})$. Then it follows that $z \in B(y, \varepsilon) \cap A\setminus\{y\}$. Thus, $y \in A'$. The reverse inclusion follows from the fact that if $S \subset T\subset X$ then $S' \subset T'$.

Now suppose that $x$ is not accumulation point of $A$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x, r) \cap A = \emptyset$. Let $y$ be an accumulation point of $A \cup \{ x \}$. If $y=x$, then $B(x,r) \cap (A \cup \{ x \})\setminus \{ x \})=B(x, r) \cap A \ne \emptyset$ which is contrary to our assumption. Hence, $y\ne x$. The same argument follows as in the last paragraph.

---

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

I present a neater proof with a similar idea. Note that it suffices to prove the case for adding $1$ point, as this extends to adding any finite number of points by induction.

Since $A \subseteq A \cup \{x\}$ we have $A' \subseteq (A \cup \{x\})'$. Let $y \in (A \cup \{x\})'$, so $\forall r > 0$ we have $B(y, r) \cap (A \cup \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$. If $d(x,y) = r_0$, then $\forall 0 < r' < r_0$, we have $x \notin B(x, r')$, but $B(x, r') \cap (A \cup \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$. This means that $B(x, r') \cap A \neq \emptyset$, so $y \in A'$, concluding that $(A \cup \{x\})' \subseteq A'$.